# Liquibase enddelimiter with regex cant find semicolon

Tags: regex, liquibase

I have got following sql file :

```
CREATE TABLE TERMINAL
(
   TERMINALGROUPID     VARCHAR2(32)       NOT NULL
) ;

create table USECASE  (
   DU_USECASEID        NUMBER(3)                    not null,
   constraint PK_USECASE primary key (DU_USECASEID)
) ;
```

And I'm using following delimiter  :

```
<sqlFile 
        encoding="utf8"
        path="migration/oracle/create.sql"
        endDelimiter=";\s*$"
        relativeToChangelogFile="true"
 />
```

Normally this regex finds all semicolons in that file, but Liquibase not. It stops and complain on invalid character and I see that it take all entries from that file. I need to find semicolons with regex because in other files i have semicolons inside strings.

Comment: Did you check to add double backslash for endDelimiter? Like `;\\s*$`

Comment: Yes, i've checked this but without success. I also investigate a little more deep and I've found that in liquibase [GitHub code](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/9f56b8680a8cc9527eb56e16c5e3e15374ef8e15/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/util/StringUtils.java) enddelimiter has semicolon replaced with empty string. Maybe this is the reason, but of course i'm not sure because i was not searching all liquibase code

Comment: I read about the [SQL change](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) again. Semicolon is the default anyways. There is also nothing in the docs that says you can use regex for this. What happens if you leave it out altogether.

Comment: Nathan Voxland wrote this 4 years ago : _I've made some changes and bug fixes with the end delimiters, the end delimiter is actually a regular expression, so you should be able to use endDelimiter="^/$" and it will only split on /'s that are on their own line._ [Liquibase forum](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/oracle-end-delimiter-issue)

Comment: Ok, maybe this is missing in the docs then. But I think you were right in finding out that a semicolon is simply replaced. However why would you not just leave out the `delimiter` attribute? If your SQLs are delimited by a `;` you should be good?

Comment: My problem is that inside sql strings i have semicolons like "test1;test2" and liquibase interprets this semicolon as a delimiter for new statement which is wrong. I cannot also replace this by some other character like for instance '@' because in the future from this file will be generated sql output file. And this file will containt this new '@' enddelimiter so i won't be able to run this file on database